# Recreating Poincaré section for a double pendulum

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, physics, sow-reap

I am trying to recreate the Poincaré Sections for the double pendulum as described in [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960077905006703) paper. I am unable to figure out a way to include energy values in the code. The code that I used until now is given below:

```
$Assumptions = {l1 ∈ Reals, l1 > 0, l2 ∈ Reals, 
   l2 > 0, m1 ∈ Reals, m1 > 0, m2 ∈ Reals, m2 > 0};

lagrangian = 
  1/2 (l1^2 (m1 + m2) θ1'[t]^2 + l2^2 m2 θ2'[t]^2 + 
      2 l1 l2 m2 Cos[θ1[t] - θ2[t]] θ1'[
        t] θ2'[t]) + g l1 (m1 + m2) Cos[θ1[t]] + 
   g l2 m2 Cos[θ2[t]];

<< VariationalMethods`

eom = EulerEquations[lagrangian, {θ1[t], θ2[t]}, {t}] // FullSimplify

e1 = eom[[1]]    
e2 = eom[[2]]

m2 = 1; l2 = 1; g = 1; m1 = 3; l1 = 2;

momentum1 = D[lagrangian, θ1'[t]];    
momentum2 = D[lagrangian, θ2'[t]];

hamiltonian = {momentum1 θ1'[t] + momentum2 θ2'[t]} - 
   lagrangian // Simplify

sol = Reap@
   NDSolve[{e1, 
     e2, θ1[0] == 0, θ2[0] == 0.15, θ1'[0] == 
      0, θ2'[0] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[θ1[t] == 0 && θ1'[t] > 0, 
      Sow[{θ2[t], θ2'[
         t]}]]}, {θ1, θ2}, {t, 0, 1000}];
    
ListPlot[sol[[2]], PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

How do I recreate Figures 2 and 3 from the paper?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Poincaré section in Fig. 2 is shown for
$$E_1 = E_{01} + 0.01 = -1-l_1(1+m_1) + 0.01.$$

To sample different parts of the section, you have to change two initial parameters, for example $\dot {\theta_1}(0)$ and $\dot{\theta_2}(0)$, but in a way that the total energy is $E_1$. You can use Mathematica to calculate the relationship between $\dot {\theta_1}(0)$ and $\dot{\theta_2}(0)$ if the other two initial conditions are $\theta_1(0) = \theta_2(0) = 0$:

```
Solve[(hamiltonian == -1 - l1 (1 + m1) + 1/100) /. {θ1[t] -> 0, θ2[t] -> 0}, 
  {θ1'[t]}]
```

$$ \dot{\theta_1}(0) = \frac{1}{40} \left(\sqrt{2-75 \dot{\theta_2}(0)^2}-5 \dot{\theta_2}(0)\right) $$

Now you have to rerun `NDSolve` multiple times with different initial conditions, sampling along $\dot{\theta_2}(0)$ (which I denote with `ω2`):

```
ω1[ω2_] := 1/40 (-5 ω2 + Sqrt[2 - 75 ω2^2]);

sol = Quiet@Table[Reap@NDSolve[{e1, e2, θ1[0] == 0, θ2[0] == 
        0.0, θ1'[0] == ω1[ω2], θ2'[0] == ω2, 
       WhenEvent[θ1[t] == 0 && θ1'[t] > 0, 
        Sow[{θ2[t], θ2'[t]}]]}, {θ1, θ2}, {t, 0, 1000}], 
       {ω2, -.2, .02, .01}];

ListPlot[Catenate@sol[[All, 2]], PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> PointSize[.006]]
```

[image]

To get Fig. 3, you have to change the total energy condition in the equation above, and calculate new relationship between $\dot{\theta_1}(0)$ and $\dot{\theta_2}(0)$.

Of course you can further automatize this with a general solver for $\dot{\theta_1}(0)$:

```
ω1[ω2_, ℰ_] := Derivative[1][θ1][t] /. 
  First@Solve[(hamiltonian == ℰ) /. {θ1[t] -> 0, θ2[t] -> 0, 
    Derivative[1][θ2][t] -> ω2}, {θ1'[t]}]

plotPoincare[ℰ_, {ω2min_, ω2max_, δω2_}] := Module[{sol},
  sol = Quiet@Table[Reap@NDSolve[{e1, e2, θ1[0] == 0, θ2[0] == 
         0.0, θ1'[0] == ω1[ω2, ℰ], θ2'[0] == ω2, 
        WhenEvent[θ1[t] == 0 && θ1'[t] > 0, 
         Sow[{Mod[θ2[t] + Pi, 2 Pi] - Pi, θ2'[t]}]]}, {θ1, θ2}, {t, 0, 
        1000}], {ω2, ω2min, ω2max, δω2}];
  ListPlot[Catenate@sol[[All, 2]], PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> PointSize[.01]]
  ]

ℰ2 = +1 - l1 (1 + m1) - 1/100;
ℰ3 = -1 + l1 (1 + m1) - 1/100;

plotPoincare[ℰ2, {-2, 2, .1}]
plotPoincare[ℰ3, {-8, 8, .5}]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this illuminating answer!

Answer (score 3):

We can get a 2D Poincare section for a double pendulum by first creating the Lagragian equations for the masses m1 and m2. We call the angles t1 and t2, g is the gravity constant (for an example, we set all the parameters to 1):

```
v1 = l1 t1'[t]; (*velocity of m1*)
v21 = l2 t2' [t]; (*velocity of m2 relative to m1*)
 v2 = Sqrt[v1^2 + v21^2 + 2 v1 v21 Cos[t2[t] - t1[t]]];(*velocity of m2*)
pot = - m1 g Cos[t1[t]] - m2 g Cos[t2[t]]; (*potential*)
lagrange = 
  1/2  m1 v1^2 + 1/2 m2 v2^2 - pot /. {l1 -> 1, m1 -> 1, l2 -> 1, 
    m2 -> 1, g -> 1};
eq = {D[D[lagrange, t1'[t]], t] - D[lagrange, t1[t]] == 0, 
   D[D[lagrange, t2'[t]], t] - D[lagrange, t2[t]] == 0};
```

We will solve the equations inside a manipulate, that allows to change the initial values easily. For an example we choose the section by requiring x1==0 and we plot t2 against t2'. To get the point of the Poincare section we use a "WhenEvent":

```
tmax = 1000;
Manipulate[
 ini = {t1[0] == t10, t2[0] == t20, t1'[0] == v10, t2'[0] == v20};
 pts = Reap[
    NDSolve[{eq, ini, 
       WhenEvent[t1[t] == 0, Sow[{t2[t], t2'[t]}]]}, {t1, t2}, {t, 0, 
       tmax}];
    ][[2, 1]];
 Graphics[Point[pts], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
 , {t10, 0, Pi/2}, {{t20, Pi/2}, 0, Pi/2}, {v10, 0, 1/2}, {v20, 0, 
  1/2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the details!